# How to prevent size of UIScrollView after device orientation is changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, orientation

[image]

I have `UIScrollView` on xib-file on portrait mode. When I run the application and rotate device to landscape mode I see the new bounds of the `UIScrollView`. Half of the controls inside `UIScrollView` at the bottom are inaccessible. There is no any scroller visible.

How to prevent change of the vertical size of `UIScrollView` after device orientation is changed?

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You need to set the contentSize for scrollview. Check if that is set properly. Scroller is displayed based on that.

Comment: I know - but it doesn't help:(

Comment: Can you please post some more details such as what you were trying to do and what is the exact result? Is it that the the frame you are setting in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not accepted at all? or the method itself is not getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Setup **Reference Outlet**.
2. Use the code:

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

Answer (score 0):

Change the UIScrollView's frame in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

According to the device rotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
      if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
         //set frame for scroll in portrait mode
    }
    else  if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
      //set frame for landscape
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** select your UIScrollView and change autoresize property for your scroll view like this.

[image]

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
 {
     //change sub view of scrollview accordingly to orientation
     if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
         yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
         yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,460);//change accordingly
     else
         yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,300);
         yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480,460); //change accordingly

     return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

select your UIScrollView and then from properties click on size inspector and change autoresize property for your view.

[image: see image]

Comment: This does work for me try different setting for autoresize property.